# Creating wrappers for objects returned by 3rd paty APIs

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

I am building a WPF application which uses a third party library to fetch objects which I want to allow the user to interact with.

The objects are returned as interface types. Am I right in thinking it is good practise to create wrapper classes for these objects instead of binding directly to the interface returned e.g (ICustomer)?

If so, what is the best way to do this? My current thinking is to inject the service into my view model. Then create my own version of the customer class (ClientCustomer) on the client. When I call get customers on the service it will return a list of ICustomer. For each of these, I will create a new instance of ClientCustomer passing in the ICustomer object and client customer can simply return the underlying properties. This will leave me with a list of ClientCustomer objects which I can bind to instead of binding directly to the List of ICustomer.

Is this a good approach? I'm also unsure how to handle complex types which ICustomer contains. For instance ICustomer has a List of Bank accounts IBankAccount. Do I need to wrap the Bank Account object as well?

Thanks

Comment: I would always "implement" their interface meaning creating methods that accept those types.  From there prior to working on the content, validation can and should be done before it gets too deep into the system.  This as well as validating the expected output from these methods as well because we all hate "Null Reference not set to instance of object" errors.

Comment: @JohnPeters - Thanks I'm not quite clear what you mean. So instead of ClientCustomer having ICustomer injected into its constructor, you would have ClientCustomer implement the ICustomer interface?

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I wasn't thinking correctly in prior post.  But yes, I would either create a wrapper class or a class that takes in types via a method interface or a property.  The concept is to contain the object in a manner that your class has 100% control over what is allowed in, and what is returned.  In addition it can alter content not know by the outside.